# How to select a persons lastname in php from mysql table and put it in a $_Session variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, mysqli

I want a straightforward answer with an example (NO LINKS please) to see how I can retrieve a specific person's last name from a table in a MySQL database using PHP and save it into a variable (i.e. `$_Session`). I have been looking for this question and I don't get anything related to one row in PHP. If this can be done better with mysqli* functions then I would be glad to see it.

Example

```
$getData = "SELECT lastname FROM person WHERE name='$name'";
$getData_q = mysql_query($getData) or die('Error');
```

Then i want something like this:

```
$_SESSION['lastame']=$getData_q; <- Please correct me,
```

I'm not asking to get a `lastname` from an input, I'm asking to get it from the table person in the database with the SELECT.

Comment: This sounds like a *Craigslist* listing for a script under the FREE section...though you should also add *"No up-to-date database libraries please, only deprecated ones."* On the serious side, you have a syntax error in your first snippet.

Comment: so, have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Also, try using uppercase, `$_SESSION`, not `$_Session`

Comment: Also, `$getData_q` is the query, not the fetched results. I would advise looking into switching to `PDO` *(`mysqli_*` is okay, but I think `PDO` is easier in my opinion)*

Comment: Yes, I know I didnt have a " at the end of my snippet and yes I have $_SESSION in my code. I dont have any errors like those being shown because I made them correctly, I just want a solution to getting something into the $_SESSION variable. I tried making a new query and making a new function. I when I use echo ".$_SESSION['lastname']." I get nothing.

Comment: That is because you are sending the query to the session, not the results of the query. You need to fetch assoc or the like.

Comment: @Rasclatt is the fetch necessary with a while?

Comment: Not if you are expecting only one row.

Comment: you have $_SESSION, great, but we are not ficking psychic

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$getData_q = mysqli_fetch_object($getData_q);
$_SESSION['lastame']=$getData_q->lastame;
```

But ensure that that num rows is greater than 0 and data would return a single row.